# Filter view results by day of the week instead of the date - Date Module

Tags: views, datetime

I have a view which includes a date field, and I'd like to provide a filter for users to show only items from a certain day of the week. From what I can see, though, the date filter only allows you to select the date by which to filter. Is it possible to create a filter which will allow users to show, say, all nodes which have a date that falls on a Wednesday?

Comment: The date filter will allow you to set the filters by a particular "year" or by particular "month & year"  by changing the granularity of date filter settings

Comment: Yes I realize that, but I am looking for a way to filter by day of the week. If I select a granularity of "day", the user still has to filter by a particular date, and cannot select "Friday" or "Wednesday".

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the [Views Day of Week](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dow) module to filter the result by day of week. Here is a quote from it's project page:

> ... Views Day of Week provides a simple filter plugin for Views 3 to enable filtering content that should be visible based on the current day of the week.
>
> **Example**: With this module you can select that some content should be visible only on Mondays, some on Tuesdays and Thursdays and some only on Fridays.